# in javamail, is there a way the sever can return headers with message?

Tags: jakarta-mail

in my app, need to scan all emails in an email account, and filter them use a special time with email's sent date.
but in javamail, each message's sent date are not cached in client at first, when u need it, u must pull it from server, it costs too much time.
i already tried FetchProfile:

```
msgs = folder.getMessages(beginLine, endLine);
FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
folder.fetch(msgs, fp);
```

but it just simply pull headers from sever one by one.
so, i want to know, is there any way when i use `folder.getMessages()`, the server can return sent date/header with message? thx!

and, i am use using pop3 and imap, imap is little easier, but i can not just use imap, because i can decide email account use which protocol.

Comment: Folder.fetch doesn't pull the headers one by one; it sends a single IMAP command that pulls the headers for all the specified messages.  If that's not what you're seeing, something else is wrong.  Can you provide the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) showing the problem?

Comment: unlike IMAP, POP3 does not send command to get headers for messages, i can not just use IMAP, some of my app's users haven't opened IMAP yet.

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you having a problem with IMAP or POP3?  With POP3, the headers can be downloaded separately using the POP3 TOP command, and JavaMail will do this if you only access the headers.  If you access the message content, the entire message, including the headers, will be downloaded.  Since POP3 has no way to fetch ENVELOPE information for more than one messages at a time, if you use Folder.fetch it will simply iterate over all the messages and use the TOP command to fetch and cache the headers.

Comment: the thing is, i need to login in user's account to filter and download emails, and this process have a time limit, so i must do it quickly , but the way which POP3 gets the headers is the bottleneck. anyway, thx for reply, i've found another way to fix my problem.

Comment: There's a limit to what you can do given the POP3 protocol.  If you've found a solution to your problem, please post it here so that others can benefit.